# Marking a particular pixel value in a grayscale image

Tags: python, image-processing

I have a grayscale image and a threshold. The pixel values exceeding the threshold should be marked as either blue color or "+" sign.

```
thresh_img = np.zeros((r,c))
thresh_img[:,:] = img[:,:]
thresh_img[thresh_img > 40] = 0
```

How to do this in python?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Post the code

Comment: is that really all you have? what is np? and r and c?

Comment: r, c are rows and columns of the image, img is the image that has to be thresholded and np is short form of numpy.

Comment: Your code is wrong so far, **since your image has just 1 channel**. You need a RGB image to do what you want. You should use a library to have such a proper data structure.

Answer (score 2):

Use [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) to identify the values, then use `numpy.nonzero` or `numpy.where` to get their indices. For images or matrices the indices can be directly used as positions. Then use `matplotlib.plot(x, y, 'b+')`

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is using the PIL library (http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/). 
First, you create an array to store values. Then you open the image and using a for loop, you iterate over all the pixels it has. Depending on the color of the pixel, you store a '+' or something else (you don't specify what so I'll suppose it's the color, which you can store as a single number since grays have similar R G and B values). So, I might do something this way:

```
from PIL import Image
cols = []
im = Image.open("dead_parrot.jpg") #Can be many different formats.
pix = im.load()
w = im.size[0]
h = im.size[1]
for i in range(w):
    row = []
    for j in range(h):
        red = pix[i,j][0]
        if red > threshold:
            row.append('+')
        else:
            row.append(str(red))
    cols.append(row)
print(cols)
```

I believe this should do the job. Could you try it?

Comment: It is showing an error 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'load'

Comment: look at the code: `im = Image.open("dead_parrot.jpg")`. im comes from a picture, it shouldn't have anything to do with numpy